# How to set Control Position at top of Parent Control in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I don't know how to set the Image at top of the ParentView(StackPanel) in WPF.

Here is my XAML Code :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="280" Margin="0 0 0 16" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            cal:Message.Attach="[MouseEnter] = [NavigationMenuItemMouseEnter()]; [MouseLeave] = [NavigationMenuItemMouseLeave()]">
            <Image x:Name="MenuIcon" Source="{Binding ImageName}" Width="25" Height="22" Margin="30 0 0 0" />
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListViewItemMenu" Content="{Binding Path=Header}" 
                         Visibility="{Binding ListViewItemVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
                         FontSize="20" Style="{DynamicResource NoEffectHoverListBoxItem}" 
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="25 0"
                         Foreground="{Binding TitleForegroundColor}" />
            <Expander x:Name="ExpanderMenu" Header="{Binding Path=Header}" 
                      Visibility="{Binding ExpanderVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
                      IsExpanded="False" Width="210" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                      Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="{Binding TitleForegroundColor}" 
                      FontSize="20" Padding="25 0"
                      Style="{DynamicResource ArrowlessExpanderTemplate}"
                      PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Expander_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubItems}" 
                          Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          Height="210">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid MouseEnter="SubMenuMouseEnter" MouseLeave="SubMenuMouseLeave">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid Name="SubMenuItemBar" Background="{DynamicResource White_200}" Margin="0 10 0 8" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="6 0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Padding="0 5" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Expander>
        </StackPanel>
```

This xaml shows like this.
[image: XAML Code]

As we can see here, when I click the expander, there list is showing up and expander and list is rolling up, but image's position is static.
So I hope to change the position at the top of the parentview(stack panel)

Please let me know how to solve this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `VerticalAlignment="Top"`?

Comment: To `<Image>` params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to add VerticalAlignment="Top" in Image.

```xml
<Image x:Name="MenuIcon" Source="{Binding ImageName}" Width="25" Height="22" Margin="30 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```